# Assign value to setter method using reflection

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection

How do i create object at runtime and set values all the setter values in the object ?
I am generating below classes at runtime using jsonschema2pojo.Classes field can change 
,

```
class Foo
(

int a ;
int b;

List <Abc> list;
//getters and setter ommited
}

class Abc
{

int c ;
int d;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an idea of how we can achieve this via reflection :

```
class Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    List<Abc> list;
}

class Abc {
    int c;
    int d;
}


public class FillSettersThroughReflection {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Method[] publicMethods = Foo.class.getMethods(); //get all public methods
        final Foo foo = Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); //will only work when you will have default constructor
        //using java 8
        Stream.of(publicMethods).filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("set"))
                .forEach(method -> {
                    //you can write your code
                });

        //in java older way
        for (Method aMethod : publicMethods) {
            if (aMethod.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                aMethod.invoke(foo, <your value>); //call setter-method here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can put your conditions after `set` filter then call `invoke` method after pass value.

Comment: Thanks @Holger it happened by mistake.